# A&M forms on submit internal server error

Tags: form, error, plugin-amforms

I've got [A&M forms](https://github.com/am-impact/amforms) set up and I'm trying to get a assets field to upload files.

My current form code is below. If I remove the first line then the form works correctly but I can't get a file upload to work without it as I am unable to figure out how to manually code the file upload field.

My current commented out code for the file was cribbed from a previous ExpressionEngine install and uses some Javascript to allow styling of the field. Everything seems to work here as I can upload a file but due to the internal server error on submit I can't be sure.

Without line 1 the form works but I can't get file uploads. How do I resolve this?

```html
{% set form = craft.amForms.getForm('requestQuote') %}


<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal contact-form">
{# This should always be here! #}
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="amForms/submissions/saveSubmission">

{# Insert your forms handle. #}
<input type="hidden" name="handle" value="requestQuote">

{# Optional: Redirect URL. Will redirect to current page by default. #}
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="contact/thankyou">

{# Optional: Anti-spam protection. #}
  {{ craft.amForms.displayAntispam() }}

  {# Optional: Google reCAPTCHA protection. #}
  {{ craft.amForms.displayRecaptcha() }}

  <fieldset class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="sr-only control-label" for="textinput">Name</label>
        <input id="name" name="fields[fullName]" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control input-md" required>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="sr-only control-label" for="Email">Email</label>
        <input id="email" name="fields[emailAddress]" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control input-md" required>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="sr-only control-label" for="phone">Phone</label>
        <input id="phone" name="fields[telephoneNumber]" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control input-md">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="sr-only control-label" for="companyName">Company Name</label>
        <input id="company" name="fields[companyName]" type="text" placeholder="Company Name" class="form-control input-md">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <label class="sr-only control-label" for="budget">Budget</label>
        <select id="budget" name="fields[budget]" class="form-control" required>
          <option disabled="" selected>expected budget</option>
        <option value="< $2,500">< $2,500</option>
        <option value="$2,500-$5,000">$2,500-$5,000</option>
        <option value="$5,000-$10,000">$5,000-$10,000</option>
        <option value="$10,000-$15,000">$10,000-$15,000</option>
        <option value="> $15,000">>$15,000</option>
        <option value="More Details below">More Details below</option>
        <option value="I'm not sure">I'm not sure</option>
        </select>
    </div>

{#
// commmented out for testing
// unstyled field added below this commented block
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <span id="changefree">{{ form.displayField('attachment') }}</span>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="fields[attachment][]" id="fields-attachment" class="form-control" disabled placeholder="Upload File">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="browse btn btn-default extra-pad" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Browse</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    #}

    {{ form.displayField('attachment') }}



    <!-- Textarea -->
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <label class="sr-only control-label" for="projectDetails">Project Details and Message</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="project_details" name="fields[projectDetails]" placeholder="Project Details and Message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <button id="singlebutton" type="submit" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>

  </fieldset>



</form>
```

Comment: The underlying error message for the 500 Internal Server Error is either going to be logged in `craft/storage/runtime/logs` if Craft generated it, or your web server's error logs if your web server generated it.

Comment: The server error log is empty on my host but I'm not sure what to look for in the /logs file for Craft.

Comment: Nuke the logs, reproduce the issue, then search for `[error]` in the `craft.log` files or in the `phperrors.log` if you have that one, too.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`to the form tag? See (https://github.com/am-impact/amforms/issues/64)

Comment: @WolframGehring Can you add that as an answer so I can mark it correct. Thanks.

Comment: @CreateSean Glad it´s working now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to upload assets with your form, you will need to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag:
`<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" ...`